# C# subtraction of strings

Tags: c#

I am sorry for that bad Title, but basicaly my problem is really simple. I got 1 string which is basic alphabet and the second string which is gonna be part of the alphabet (8 characters) which user will fill up by himself. If 2 characters are the same, they will get removed and then rest of characters will be in the TextBox3. could someone pls help me ?

```
string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_*";
string special = TextBox2.Text;
```

Comment: This sounds like an homework. On S.O. we don't do those for students. We can help you on issues you face though, that is if you show some effort. What did you try so far?

Comment: In addition to showing what you've tried so far, it's good to show a sample input, with the expected output. From just your question alone, it's not clear what you expect to happen if the user input were 'stalls', for instance. Does alphabet get changed? Does special get changed? What 2 characters need to be the same?

Comment: Basically i am trying to make a code which would require 2 passwords to decode itself. 1 password is a series of numbers from 0-9 in any order and the second is series of 8 letters from alphabet, again all of those letters have to be unique for it to work. Then i will compare letters with numbers above and get 2 numbers which gonna make an basic structure of the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you want to check the existence of substring and remove from the parent string, Try this

```
        string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_*";
        string special = textBox2.Text;
        if (alphabet.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(special))
        {
            textBox3.Text =  alphabet.Replace(special, "");
        }
```

Comment: Thx man, it really helped me out, started like 5 days ago with programming.